# What does it mean by never spin in sleep()?

Tags: operating-system, synchronization, spinlock

I am studying ways of synchronization in multithreaded system.
My reference states some rules to remember for concurrent programming.
One of them is "never spin in sleep()", but I have problem understanding what does it mean. Clearly a process can't do anything while sleeping.

Does it mean that we should not sleep() while holding a spinlock? or something else?

Comment: Why didn't you ask your reference? Is it from a book? Does it state why not?

Comment: By the way: I am guessing it means `while(!condition) { sleep(someTime)}`.